# Google App Engine Objectify querying big objects VS separated objects (head and body)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have one entity object (kind) for storing all information from user's "advertisement". It includes keys for photographs, contact information and so on.
But I need only few things from all this to query the object.

Using Google App Engine (Java) with Objectify.

My question is this.
Is it more powerful to have entity object just for queries ("head" - with Title, Price, City) and another entity object to all extra unindexed details?
Or is it ok to have all this in one entity object and just tag other properties as unindexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to have the details on the same kind, it will save you from needing additional trips to the datastore.  As you noted, it is a good idea to mark any properties you do not need to query or order by as unindexed since it improves write performance and reduces storage space.

You might find the articles on [mastering the datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/datastore/overview.html) useful.  They explain more of the details about how entities and indexes are built and stored.

Comment: Thank you very much. So even if my site is "eBay like", I should use one entity object to store all advertisement information? And I can query through it with no extra performance (and traffic) load? The details of advertisement will be loaded after click on advertisement's head, so I really don't need them before.

Comment: @kovalu If you will be displaying the information together, I would keep it together -- it will be more efficient (since you need fewer trips to the datastore).  If you never need to display the information together, you could separate the entities.  You might also want to do a simple benchmark for your app, but people generally find the difference in performance between loading a 'small' and 'large' entity is negligible.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. In list with all advertisements (which users will search like on eBay), there will be just header information. If they click on ad's title, I will need the rest of information in ad's body. A lot of information are shared, so on the ad's detail I also need information from ad's head. My current solution is to have them separated, bud on ad's detail I query them both to get all information from head and body.

Comment: @kovalu Sounds like you might want to look at combining them.  Or at least benchmark it, you'll probably see relatively large savings on the detail display and only a marginal (if any) increase in the cost to display the list.